# Dynamic overflow-x for table columns?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a table with all columns at a set width, except for the last column, which takes up an undetermined width. In the last column, I have another table with more content at a set width that I want to be scrollable.

For users with high resolutions, all the content will be visible. For users with small resolutions, I want the content in the last column to be scrollable.

**Example of what I am trying to create:**

[View full screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60vGk.png)

[image]

**My current code:**

```
<style>
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

td {
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:11px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
    height:50px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

table.innertable td {
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    border-top:0;
    border-bottom:0;
    border-left:0;
}

</style>

<table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;">

<tr>
    <td style="width:100px;">&#8592; 100 px &#8594;</td>
    <td style="width:200px;">&#8592; 200 px &#8594;</td>
    <td style="width:200px;">&#8592; 200 px &#8594;</td>
    <td style="width:200px;">&#8592; 200 px &#8594;</td>
    <td>&#8592; The rest of the space &#8594;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td style="width:100px;">&#8592; 100 px &#8594;</td>
    <td style="width:200px;">&#8592; 200 px &#8594;</td>
    <td style="width:200px;">&#8592; 200 px &#8594;</td>
    <td style="width:200px;">&#8592; 200 px &#8594;</td>
    <td>
        <div style="overflow-x:scroll;">
        <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" class="innertable">
        <tr>
        <td style="width:200px;">&#8592; 200 px &#8594;</td>
        <td style="width:200px;">&#8592; 200 px &#8594;</td>
        <td style="width:200px;">&#8592; 200 px &#8594;</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PTjqL/

Comment: I wonder if [Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media1) would work/be reliable for presenting browsers with a screen size over a certain number?

Comment: See examples XXIV and XXV here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#width (Also [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries).)

Comment: I tried using max-width and min-width, but I couldn't find a way to create what I have in my example.

Comment: If it worked, I would think it would only affect the case when it's above the floor of not overflowing. I haven't done many media queries, though, so I'm not real sure how to use them.

Comment: Ok, here I was able to change the text color of the `td` elements with a media query (in FF8): http://jsfiddle.net/PTjqL/1/

Comment: See my media query example. I'm cautiously optimistic it will work for you. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

What about limiting the width?

http://jsfiddle.net/PTjqL/4/ <- Like this.

**EDIT:** The change is `<div style="overflow-x:scroll; width: 200px;">`. I've limited the width of the div. If you don't limit it, it will cover the max size as it can, and it will never do overflow-x ;)

Comment: You should post your actual improvement/fix within the answer, along with the fiddle. `:)`

Comment: Yeah.. I was able to get to that point, but it doesn't for people with larger resolutions - which is very important.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** - Note, it appears to work beautifully in Chrome and FF8, but none of the IE versions do.

However, an [IE conditional](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) could be used to detect IE and use a small Javascript to detect viewport size and modify the element as appropriate (and add a `window.resize` handler). So all is not lost...

**EDIT 2** - Well, the [MSDN `@media` docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms530813.aspx) seem to suggest it should work. There is a nearly identical example, for instance. Hmm...

**EDIT 3** - If I remove the `and (max-width:1280px)` from the query, the text changes blue in IE9. I suspect it does/should work, but there's something else going on (maybe quirks mode is being triggered?).

---

This *seems* to work, but I am certainly unsure about whether all browsers and versions will support it. But what this does is add the `overflow: scroll` to the `div#scrollable` when the viewport is `< 1280px`. If you open the link below in it's own browser window (I'm using FF8 to test) and try resizing it's width, you'll see the blue text turning on and off and the overflow being added and taken away.

For some examples and decent descriptions, see:

[Using media queries with `@import` and `@media`](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/introducing-media-queries.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_4)

**CSS Media Query**

```
<style type="text/css">

/* This is what I added as far as the conditional style. 
   Note, the blue text is only for effect. */

@media only screen and (max-width:1280px) {
    .innertable td {
        color: blue !important;
    }
    #scrollable {
        overflow-x: scroll !important;
    }
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

td {
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:11px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
    height:50px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

table.innertable td {
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    border-top:0;
    border-bottom:0;
    border-left:0;
}
</style>
```

**HTML Modification**

```
<!-- Note the ID attribute -->
<div id="scrollable">
  <table cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" class="innertable">
    <tr>
      <td style="width:200px;">&#8592; 200 px &#8594;</td>
      <td style="width:200px;">&#8592; 200 px &#8594;</td>
      <td style="width:200px;">&#8592; 200 px &#8594;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

http://jfcoder.com/test/mediaquery.html

Comment: I would really like it to be compatible with as many browsers as possible. IE7 at the very least.

Comment: I don't know, it doesn't *seem* to work when I add the line `and (max-length:1280px)`. You might ask a question here on SO about why that doesn't work in IE. I believe it should. If not, you could go the conditional/script approach for IE only.